# What is a better way to add property to objects in array in response from API, React.js?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make an app using API from https://swapi.co/
They have no pictures in their response so I thought to add them myself after fetching the data.

I'm fetching data from API in action like that

```
export const fetchCharacters = () => async dispatch => {
    const response = await fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/');
    const data = await response.json();
    const results = await data.results;
    dispatch({
        type: FETCH_CHARACTERS,
        payload: results
    });
}
```

After that in reduce

```
case FETCH_CHARACTERS :
            return {
                ...state,
                characters: action.payload
            }
```

To load this data to my component:

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchCharacters();
    }
```

After this `this.props.characters` is an array of objects.

So I've been thinking how can I add pictures for each character?
I'm thinking something like mapping over objects, adding new property to each one. And to assign right picture to character I'm thinking naming pictures `0.jpg, 1.jpg`, and then in map function just doing somehing like:

```
character.pic = `link/${index}.jpg`;
```

Is it a good way of achieving this? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Is this question asking how to map or asking if your idea is a good idea?

Comment: the `index` does not sound like a permanent property of each character. Maybe extract the `id` number from the `url` property of each character.

Answer (score 0):

you can not change props value. i am sharing 2 way that you can use.

One is

```
 const resultObj = {};
    resultObj.result = await data.results;
    resultObj.imgPath = "path of image"
 dispatch({
        type: FETCH_CHARACTERS,
        payload: resultObj
    });
```

Second is here

```
this.setState({characters:this.props.fetchCharacters})
```

Now you can add key in state